# Strange rotations in vertices of mesh

Tags: mesh, vertices

I was just in mid of editing a mesh I copied with ctrl+D and moved elsewhere, as I recognized that all vertices are strangely rotated and not all in same direction. Few are rotated same but others are completely different. I have no idea how this could happened and using ctrl+A to apply rotation didn't help at all.
I hope somebody has an answer for this and can help.
Thanks for the attention.

And if somebody by the way could explain how to make the ctrl+ things look like buttons I would appreciate that help too. :D[image]

Comment: Do you have a modifier that is affected by the grid?

Comment: The only modifier I did use was subdivision surface and I did use a tool named booltool, with which it's easier to use boolean to seperate or connect meshes. Nothing else.

Comment: The image is showing that 'normal' axis are displayed: look at the bottom bar

Comment: Thanks; I once set it to normal and forgot to set it back, now everything is fine again :)